# Is there any way to have dynamic routes/components in vuejs router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4, vuejs-routing

*Hi beautiful Vuejs developers out there!*
I have a little problem with routing many Vue components/pages dynamically. In this scenario I am using nested routes to have a couple of routes for my layout components and hundreds of child routes for my pages and as you can imagine I'll have to type many child routes statically or manually, and then add more when I need more child routes in the future code changes but I need a solution to simplify/solve this problem with more efficient/better way like adding those routes from what user types after the layout in the url... here is my example code code:

```
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
{
  {
    path: '/student',
    component: () => import('layouts/StudentLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: () => import('pages/student/Dashboard.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: () => import('pages/student/Profile.vue'),
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

As you see in this code I have a layout named Student and it has two children but I'll have to type manually hundreds of child routes for this layout and other layouts is there any way to dynamically set up those routes with what users enter after the layout name like /student/dashboard or /layout/page and match it with a component name? I mean like params in Angular, can I use the param value itself inside the router to say?

```
 {
    path: ':pagename',
    component: (pagename) => import('pages/student/' + pagename + '.vue'),
 },
```

let me know if there is an efficient way to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would, personally, not use this, or advise such an approach, nor have I done it, but this idea came to me when I read your question:

My best guess would be to have a handler component which renders a component dynamically based on a route parameter (say you have `/:subpage` as a child to `/student` and the handler component is set to that route), and an exception handler around that to show a 404 page when the user types in an inexistent/unsupported route.

For example, I would dynamically import the component by the route parameter into a predefined let (e.g. `let SubpageComponent;` outside the try catch block), have a try catch block around the dynamic import assignment for the respective error where catch would set the variable to a 404 page. Then I would add the SubpageComponent into the data() of the component doing the rendering of the route.

---

Edit

I've written out come code that, maybe, makes sense.

It's based on https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

your routes definition, changed

```
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
    {
        path: '/student',
        component: () => import('layouts/StudentLayout.vue'),
        children: [
            {
                path: '/:subpage',
                component: () => import('pages/student/SubpageRenderer.vue'),
                props: true,
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

SubpageRenderer.vue

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ['subpage'],
    data() {
        return {
            currentSubpage: () => import(`./${subpage}.vue`)
        }
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <component :is="currentSubpage"></component>
</template>
```

Instead of using the `currentSubpage` import, you can also use the `subpage` route prop to bind `:is` if `subpage` is the name of a registered component.

Since this would get only "dashboard" from the route, you'd need some namespacing, like "student-dashboard" with the help of template literals. You could make `currentSubpage` into a template literal that creates the `student-${subpage}` name.

I'd probably recommend importing the options object of the component designated by the `subpage` route parameter instead of registering all the components - if you're registering them, you might as well use vue-router the usual way :)

Also, I only think this could work! It should be tested out, and perhaps casing should be kept in mind, and maybe the Layout suffix as well (`subpage` will probably be all lowercase, and you'll probably have the components named in PascalCase). After uppercasing the first letter, this could also obviously lead to both `/student/Dashboard` and `/student/dashboard` being valid routes

Comment: Hey  thank you for your reply. Do you mean using $route.params in a sub component and then handle all of the child components routing in there?

Comment: Something like that... I've thought it a bit more through now that I have access to my laptop, and here's what I've come up with as actual code, but mind you - it's untested

I'll edit it into the main comment!

Comment: Thank you so much    Your answer is really helpful I'll test it :))

Comment: I also marked your answer as the accepted one because (at least for now) I think there are no other ways!
Thanks  